# Lattice Based Cryptography domain

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto

Some cryptosystems operate on the domain of the form $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/\langle x^n-1\rangle$ and others operate on $\mathbb{Z}_q[x]/\langle x^n+1\rangle$.

What's the security impact of the two forms?